# This scripts is not login in

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am integrating Wonder Plugin Slider and I don’t have very much knowledge about wonder Plugin. How to remove watermark form top left corner. I am using 4.7 WordPress and **WonderPlugin Carousel Free Version 10.7** Do any one have any solution for the same, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also condider buying the plugin. This will remove the watermark. However, you can hide the watermark with css.

On the edit slider screen of the plugin click on Option tab.

Click on Advance Option and put following css in the Custom CSS box.

```
div.amazingslider-box-1 :nth-child(3) { 
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Now the watermark is hidden.